# Acceesing MongoDB server on Azure VM

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu

did anyone have by a chance a good article for installing MongoDB on ubuntu Server 14.
I am using MongoDb server installed on VM Ubuntu 14 on Azure, and I use this [tutroial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE8Ym.png), with last version. I add the port of mongo 27017 too. And I connect to it directly and add Database with some collections.
I can log into mongo by Putty, and access it files, even the setting is right.
But I can't access by RoboMongo or even in the browser can give me message like : It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

> [image] [![enter image description
>   here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFLs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFLs.png) [image]

I don't know where is the problem

Update:
I can access by SSH but not directly, as you see
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your `mongod.conf`, where your `bindIp` is `127.0.0.1` (localhost). This is going to prevent you from reaching mongodb from anywhere else. Try changing that `bindIp` to `0.0.0.0` and restart the `mongod` process.