# Connecting to a mongoDB server on a Windows Azure VM using Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, azure

I am attempting to setup a mongodb server on an Azure vm and can not seem to connect to it from an external client.

Here is what I have done so for:

1. I have created a windows server 2016 VM
2. I have installed mongodb as a service and started it on the new vm
3. I have added an inbound rule in the firewall for mongodb on the port 27017 with the following configuration:

   - Name: Allow MongoDB
   - Profile: All
   - Enabled: Yes
   - Action: Allow:
   - Override: No
   - Program: Any
   - Local Address: Any
   - Remote Address: Any
   - Protocol: TCP
   - Local Port: 27017
   - Remote Port: Any (The rest of the settings are also set to Any)
4. I have created a Network Security Group on Windows Azure
5. On the network security group I have set the Inbound security rules to the following configuration:

   - Priority: 100
   - Name: AllowHttp
   - Source: Any
   - Destination: Any
   - Service: Custom(Any/80)
   - Action: Allow
6. I associated the Subnet section to the virtual network of my azure vm

   I am trying to connect from my local pc to the vm's mongodb installation using robomongo with the connection type Direct Connection, Address as the vm's public ip displayed on the vm's sumamry and port 27017.
   When I attempt this I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you alter MongoDB's configuration to allow for remote connections? Assuming you didn't - I answered this nearly-exact question on StackOverflow, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39313238/272109).

Comment: Where is this file stored ? it does not seem to be in   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin where my mongoDb instalation is

Comment: Just look at the published instructions for MongoDB running on Windows. (easy to find). It talks about you needing to create a configuration file if one doesn't exist. Given you don't have a config file, I'm pretty confident the other answer I linked to is the issue you're running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added NSG rule for port 80 but you are trying to access on port 27017, so NSG will block you. Try to add Allow rule for 27017 on the NSG.

Comment: The OP showed that they created an inbound rule for 27017. But they have not configured the MongoDB server itself to allow for outside connections (which I pointed out in comments, and pointed to my answer which explains this).

Comment: The inbound rule was in Windows Firewall, not NSG

Comment: Ah. I misread. So that, coupled w/non-local-only config, seems like the core issues...

Comment: The issue was both the NSG and the lack of a config file after doing both the connection worked